# How can I make a Ubuntu Live USB with Ubuntu, GParted & HBCD?

Tags: live-usb

Is it possible to create a Ubuntu Live USB installer using Ubuntu, GParted & HBCD?

If yes could anyone brief the procedure in details please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here I got something, taken from [pendrivelinux.com](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/multiboot-create-a-multiboot-usb-from-linux/)

#### First, install the Multisystem LiveUSB Tool

1. [Download](http://liveusb.info/multisystem/install-depot-multisystem.sh.tar.bz2) and Open the Script with `Ubuntu's Archive Manager`
   [image: Open]
2. Extract the `install-depot-multiboot.sh` Script to your Desktop
   [image: Extract]
   [image: Desktop]
3. Double Click `install-depot-multiboot.sh` from your desktop and select the option to `Run in Terminal`
   [image: Run]

#### Second, how to use it

1. Insert a USB Drive
2. Launch the Script via `Applications > Accessories > MultiBoot`
3. Select your `USB Device` from the list and click `Validate`
   [image: Validate]
4. Now simply Drag and Drop an ISO into the Window to add the Distribution (repeat the process to add more ISOs)
   [image: ISO]
5. Once finished, restart your PC, set your boot menu to boot from the USB device, Select the Distro you want to Boot and enjoy!

Comment: Nice one, i will give a try? Can i include GPARTED & HBCD ?

Comment: Hey Drie, thanks for this nice tutorial. I successfully created a live bootable usb containing gparted & ubuntu 14.04.1 A few steps didn't work the way mentioned but I used my own knowledge to get it done.

Answer (score 1):

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallAndBootMultipleLinuxFromPendriveFlashDriveUSBDisk

Should allow you to do that.

Comment: Please elaborate your answer.

Comment: It lets you boot multiple distros from a USB.

Comment: I Know that, i have already found that link. But i need the exact procedure for making live usb for all the ubuntu versions.

Comment: But each distro version is going to take up space, and for each additional partition you add, you bring doom to the USB device.  I'd recommend you just keep multiple USB sticks for each livecd and install with persistence

Comment: What you mean by persistance?

Comment: Updated the question..

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Ubuntu program `Startup Disk Creator` to put Ubuntu on a stick. You will have to specify the .iso file to use and carefully provide it with the device you want to install to. Before you proceed with installing you can tell the Disk Creator that you want persistent memory and specify how much (with a maximum of 4GB for a big stick).

The installed system will have the Ubuntu version you selected, and will have gparted.

You can then boot the USB stick and partition disks or install Ubuntu from it, etc. You can also install additional packages on it (I wouldn't update linux, however) and make other changes. Due to the persistence setting these will be saved to the USB stick from boot-to-boot.

In his comment I believe @Lord of Time was referring to the fact that flash memory has a somewhat limited lifetime, limited in the number of writes to its sectors before those particular sectors are marked lost and the flash memory loses capacity. The controller on the flash memory stick tries to spread the wear around the stick. If I understand his comment, that's the reason for using a couple of sticks and using only part of each, rather than combining them--it should allow them to last longer.

It should also be simpler, and therefore less troublesome, but a little more expensive.