# Persistent Live Usb using netbook

Tags: usb, persistence

hello second question xD 
as i said earlier i have a netbook and was looking thru persistent live usb making and all guides seem to need that i boot from live cd but my netbook doesn't have an optical drive :/
so here's my question(sorry if it has been asked before) can i make a persistent ubuntu live usb using my netbook? what i'm trying to achieve here is getting a 32gb usb drive and have my own portable computer here (ubuntu takes about 2gb so 30gb left for all my other files "music,video,documents,additional packages,etc." can i do that? as far as i could find the maximum persistent storage i could have is 4gb which is a real waste for a 32gb drive :/
thanks for all the help :)
best regards,
Raif Felemban (aka ubunoob) :P

Comment: i was thinking can i split the usb into two different parts? like C and D then have live ubuntu on C whie the D is used to store additional media and files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### First

- If you want to have a persistent storage in a USB Flash Drive, I recommend you to do it    from Windows, tutorial [here](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3), or if you want to make it from Ubuntu, check my answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/150536/64580).

#### Second

- If you want to split your USB Flash Drive into partitions, I recommend you to use the **Disk Utility** or **GParted Partition Editor**. Tell me if you want a tutorial to do it.

Comment: thanks :) i'll try the windows since i'm not very good with the terminal and stuff :/

Comment: the usb universal installer seems to have a maximum persistent storage of 4gb :/ is it impossible to have more persistent storage? or am i not understanding what it means? as i said i want the usb to act as if it was my hdd everything stored in it nothing gets deleted with shut down or reboot. so i can have it with me wherever i go and just boot from it when i travel in any computer and have everything in it instead of carrying around my netbook...... sorry for so many questions xD

Comment: Really? I didn't know that, since I never had a 32GB UFD, hehe. Maybe you can try another way, just browse that [page](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3), you can find many alternatives on the left sidebar :)

Comment: ok thanks :) i love the ubuntu community really fast responses with good information :) thanks again :)

Comment: Oh or you can make partitions to your UFD. Since the maximum persistent storage is 4GB, then part it 5 or 6GB for Ubuntu and the rest for your files. Good luck and you're welcome :)

Comment: wait if i make partitions well ubuntu detect it as external storage? :O sounds like a great idea!! so basically i could have my 32gb drive split to 8gb for ubuntu and 24gb for other files? think i just found a solution (more like given one xD) thanks again!! you were great help! :D

Comment: Yes you can do that. Ubuntu will detect it as another partition which you can mount and unmount. Your welcome (again), wish you luck! :D