# Accidentally deleted the Ubuntu partition

Tags: boot, grub2, dual-boot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Grub rescue - error: unknown filesystem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/119597/grub-rescue-error-unknown-filesystem)

I have a netbook with a dualboot for Windows7 and Ubuntu. I accidentally deleted the partition for Ubuntu then after I restart my netbook it goes directly to the error: `unknown filesystem grub rescue>`.

I have read some of the threads but most of them require a LiveCD. Is there a way to fix this error without using a LiveCD?

I have an installer of Ubuntu on a flash drive will that one work since I don't have a DVD ROM available?

Answer (score 2):

You can install GRUB on your hard disk. You can do this by using putting the LiveCD on a flash disk ( [How can I make a Ubuntu Live USB with Ubuntu, GParted & HBCD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/150501/how-to-make-live-usb-with-ubuntu-gparted-hbcd-in-a-usb-for-installation) )

1. Boot to the Flash Disk. When you get the Ubuntu Live Desktop, Open terminal ( [What is a terminal and how do I open and use it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38162/what-is-the-terminal) ) and type the following:

   ```
   sudo grub
   ```

   This will get you a **grub>** prompt (i.e. the grub shell).
2. At grub>. enter these commands

   ```
   find /boot/grub/stage1
   ```

   This will return a location. If you have more than one, select the installation that you want to provide the grub files.
3. **This is important**: what was returned for the find command use it in the next line for the "?" -

   ```
   root (hd?,?)
   ```

   Again use the value from the find command i.e. if find returned `(hd0,1)` then you would enter `root (hd0,1)`
4. Next enter the command to install grub to the mbr

   ```
   setup (hd0)
   ```
5. Finally exit the grub shell

   ```
   quit
   ```

Now you are done. Reboot the machine.

---

Another option is to run this command:

```
grub-install /dev/hda
```

Comment: grub not installed and somehow I'm unable to install it on my Ubuntu 12.04 livecd.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply reinstall Ubuntu from USB on deleted partition space.

Another way of acting is to recover deleted partition using "TestDisk" for example.

Answer (score 0):

No. You must fix it with LiveCD because You deleted GRUB which is responsible for booting system.

Comment: I have an installer of Ubuntu on a flashdrive will that one work since I don't have a dvd rom available? Thanks

Comment: When you boot flashdrive select Try Ubuntu instead of Install in boot options

Comment: GRUB is installed in the MBR, but that just transfers control to GRUB as installed in Ubuntu's `/boot` directory. If the Ubuntu system is gone, GRUB is won't work. You *might* be able to boot the Windows system by giving all the right commands on the boot menu to chain-load into the Windows boot loader, but what you really need to do is install some self-contained boot loader to the MBR. `syslinux` will do this, and you can install it from the Ubuntu live USB, but I'm haven't done it and don't know how. Hopefully someone will post an answer about this; otherwise, I might look into it myself.

Comment: Can you give more details on what needs to be done?

Answer (score 0):

`grub rescue>` is happening because you deleted Ubuntu, and along with it the /boot folder, which contains vital files. You must use a LiveCD to install a bootloader - either GRUB, or use the Windows CD to reinstall the Windows bootloader. I suggest LILO (Linux Loader), but like the fellow who suggested `syslinux`, I am not sure how to install it. There are Ubuntu docs which document this, I believe - and lots of forum threads. @AthloX: GRUB IS installed on the MBR, just has no /boot.