# I installed and uninstalled ubuntu and now i can not merge 2 volumes?

Tags: partitioning

I installed ubuntu in my lappy and i think i converted it from dynamic to basic or basic to dynamic , i don't know specifically . But the problem is that now i am again using windows 8 and there is a 30 GB free space that i want to merge with my other partition but it is not showing extend volume option . Also , all the other volumes apart from C(where windows is installed) are showing as 1 . How can i merge my 2 volumes ?

Answer (score 0):

[How can I make a Ubuntu Live USB with Ubuntu, GParted & HBCD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/150501/how-can-i-make-a-ubuntu-live-usb-with-ubuntu-gparted-hbcd) shows how to create a LiveUSB distro.

Once the LiveUSB is ready, boot from the LiveUSB and then launch gparted which will enable changing the partitions on your hard drive, as long as the empty space is contiguous with the other ext4 partition.